# alternative to winmerge but in 64bit

Tags: php, windows, debugging

Do you know any software that works like winmerge? But is for 64 bit win7 OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use WinMerge just fine on Win7 x64. It works great.

Comment: how long have you been using it ?, didn't you experienced any issues at all? , to what directory did you install it? , because I think by default, most win executable files are being installed a program files (x86) ..did you leave the default or you placed it at the real program files directory of the 64bit win 7?

Comment: I installed to the default folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge. I've not had any problems at all using it on Win7 x64.